# Create XML document at given path

Tags: c#, xml, linq, silverlight-5.0, savefiledialog

It's very clear from the title that I want to create a XML document in my Silverlight 5 app at certain path. I know we can use `XDocument` available in `System.Xml.Linq` to create XML file. As I understand,  the file is created in "My Documents" folder if we use `XDocument`. How can I save XML document to desired path? Is it possible to save XML document to desired path with elevated trust in Silverlight 5 without "Save File Dialog"?

**UPDATE:** Though there is a method `Save()` available in `XDocument` there is no overload for `Save()` in Silverlight 5 which accepts `string` parameter otherwise it would be easy to send path to `Save()`. I tried to save using `StreamWriter`. Below is my code:

```
using (var outfile = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Tejas\Desktop\Sample.xml"))
{
       var doc = new XDocument(new XElement("Root", new XElement("Child", "content")));
       doc.Save(outfile);
}
```

But it's giving me `System.Security.SecurityException` with the message `File operation not permitted. Access to path 'C:\Users\Tejas\Desktop\Sample.xml' is denied.` Is it because my Silverlight 5 application is not trusted? One more thing I want to mention that *I don't want to achieve it using "SaveFileDialog"*.

Comment: [`XDocument.Save()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.save%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @har07. Thanks for your clue..!! But no overload for `Save()` accepts string as a parameter so that I can pass path to `Save()`. How can I do it using `Stream` or TextWriter` or `XmlWriter`? Please help.

Answer (score 2):

You create your XDocument as you wish, fill it up with the XML-structure you like.
And at the end you can call the Save method on the XDocument to save it to a location.

A very simple Example, lets say you want to save to the location 'c:\myXMLFolder\newXMLfiles\file.xml':

```
XDocument doc = new XDocument(
    new XElement("Root",
        new XElement("Child", "content")
    )
);
doc.Save("c:\\myXMLFolder\\newXMLfiles\\file.xml");
```

Comment: I tried to use `Save()` method but it's not accepting `string` parameter. It only accepts `Stream` or `TextWriter` or `XmlWriter`. Could you tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: It should exist : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345830(v=vs.110).aspx

This method seems to be available from .NET framework 3.5, 4 and 4.5 only. So you may need to cross check if your framework version is in this range.

Comment: Silverlight 5 framework doesn't seem to support overload for `Save()` accepting `string` parameter. :-( I tried code below to create file on my desktop. But it's not appearing there:

`var sb = new StringBuilder(@"C:\Users\Tejas\Desktop\Sample.xml");
var doc = new XDocument(new XElement("Root", new XElement("Child", "content")));
TextWriter tr = new StringWriter(sb);
doc.Save(tr);`

Comment: Append this to your code you just provided :

`using (StreamWriter outfile = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Tejas\Desktop\Sample.xml"))
            {
                outfile.Write(sb.ToString());
            }`

Comment: I tried your code but unfortunately it's giving me `System.Security.SecurityException` with the message `File operation not permitted. Access to path 'C:\Users\Tejas\Desktop' is denied.
`. Is it because in-browser Silverlight restricts writing to a file on computer? Do you have any solution?

Comment: Yes silverlight restricts that for security reasons. You can try using a file save dialog to bypass this : `SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();

if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
{
    StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(saveFileDialog.OpenFile());
    streamWriter.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
    streamWriter.Close();
}`

Comment: Yes @Jeepx. But frankly speaking it doesn't suit my requirements. I want to create file seamlessly without interrupting user. Is there any other way to do so? Or do I have to make my application "trusted"?